# Merge time series dataframes and their collective additional annotation using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, time-series

I have 2 dataframes, and want to combine/merge/concat them to create multiple or one new dataframe for model training purpose. How to merge these file using pandas under this situation?

The first is a list of csv files of time-series data that look like this:

```
File name: Data1:
Col1  Col2        Col3
Time  SignalA     SignalB
1     1           4
2     5           3
.     .           .
50    3           1
```

The second contain additional info of all those files, in this format:

```
File name: Ann:
Col1          Col2       Col3       Col4
              Data1      Data2      Data3
pH            7          7.2        6  
Negative1     0          1          1
Negative2     0          0          1
Week          35         36         34
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DataFrames are named as the files so Data1 and Ann I figure out one fast solution, maybe not beautiful but fast. I will do like this:

```
Data1['Col4'] = np.nan
new_df = Ann.append(Data1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I hope it is helpful

Comment: I have found a work around, that is to insert a `Name` column with value Data1 on all rows, then merge 2 files like normal

Comment: Yeah, it is because you have to add one column and then both of these df has the same dimensions. If both of them have 4 columns you can easily merge them. I added columns with NaNs because I do not know that there can be columns with names. If you would have to has a column with nothing you can add sth like this:
`Data1['Col4'] = ''`